# Optional Variable(variable structure) in structure in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

I have to implement a data structure in c++, which have optional variable.
As

```
 struct xyz
 {
      int x;  //required
      int y;  //optional
      bool a;  // required
      bool b;  // optional
      bool c;  // optional
      std::string d; //optional
      std::string e; // required
      ........

 }
```

Some of the variables are required means fixed, but some of the variable is optional.

I can't set any default value to the variables to tell its optional, e.g. bool variable has only two states and each state has a meaning for our project. And same for integer as well every value of integer is useful data for me.

I googled but not found any satisfactory answer.

I tried with `std::vector` but it not looks good.

```
 struct xyz
 {
      int x;  //required
      std::vector<int> y;  //optional
      bool a;  // required
      std::vector<bool> b;  // optional
      ........
 }
```

In this method we can check the size of vector, if zero means variable is not present else the variable has the desired value.

But for a bit `bool` or 4 byte `int` creating a `std::vector` is overhead to data structure.

Can any one suggest out of these methods?

Comment: `I have to implement a data structure in c++` then why the `C` tag?

Comment: How about [Boost optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)?

Comment: Is it truly optional or do you actually have different structures. ie, should this not be using inheritance?

Comment: @Joaechim, yes i heard about the boost optional, but i guess for boost optional, i have to include boost library, which can't do in my project, my lib should be dependent only in std c++.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to encapsulate "optional" fields within a struct generically in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379102/best-way-to-encapsulate-optional-fields-within-a-struct-generically-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some compilers already ship with the upcoming `std::optional` - which is called [`std::experimental::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional) for now. I am already using it for some time now (GCC 4.9+) and it's in good shape.

If your compiler does not have it yet but has good-enough support for C++11/C++14, you may also use a single header from [Andrzej Krzemieński's reference implementation](https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional) to avoid the dependency to Boost.